# fgets should stop when stdin ends

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I'm trying to use `fgets` to read from `stdin`, but in small blocks. My issue is that I'm not sure what `fgets` equals when at the end of stdin. From my code, it seems that it clearly isn't `NULL` or another end of line like `\n`. What is the proper way to do this?

Code (which loops forever since `fgets` never equals `NULL`):

```
int main () 
{   
    char str1[4];
    printf("Enter stuff: ");

    while (fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != NULL && 
           fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != "\n") {

        printf("Got here");
    }

    printf("%s\n",str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` returns a `char*` . You can't compare it to `'\n'` which is a `char`

Comment: `fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != '\n'` --> `*str1 != '\n'` ?

Comment: sorry, I copied it over wrong :(. It doesn't behave correctly as a string, it just doesn't compile as a character.

Comment: You seem to be mixed up with strings, arrays, pointers and `char` values. That's normal when learn Iearning C ;)

Comment: The return pointer from `fgets()` will never match a string literal; you'd need to use `strcmp()` to compare the strings.  Besides, you don't want to read a second line (or chunk) over the first.

Comment: I want it to exit the while loop after reading one input of stdin from the command line.

Comment: @user73236 , In that case, just remove the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
while(fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != NULL && fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != '\n'){
```

to

```
while(fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != NULL){
```

or to

```
while(fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin)){
```

`fgets` returns a `char*`. You can't compare it to `'\n'` which is a `char`. This function, returns `NULL` when it encounters `EOF`. You can simulate `EOF` on `stdin` by pressing

- <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> on windows
- <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> on linux

Comment: Note that `fgets()` returns one of two values: (1) NULL when it encounters EOF (or an error on the stream), and (2) the value of its first argument, `str1` in the question.  It never returns any other value.

Comment: If I run it with "while(fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != NULL)" I get that after I input something it just waits for me to input more instead of exiting.

Comment: @user73236, If you want to exit the program after any input, Just remove the loop. It doesn't make sense why you have a loop if you want to exit after one input.

Comment: I want it to keep reading if it is all from one input, if you type some list of characters into the command line longer than 4 (in this case 4 from str1), it will loop over and over, reading in the next few characters each time. However, when it reaches the end of the line, it just waits for more input.

Comment: @user73236 , Then, what you need in the body of the loop is `if(strstr(str,"\n"))break;` or `if(strcpsn(str,"\n")==3)break;`. Note that you need to include `string.h` in order to use these functions.

Comment: @user73236 consider using `fread` or `fscanf` or your own custom function using `fgetc` in a loop, if you don't want lines.

Comment: @CoolGuy , That works, thank you! Perhaps I should consider fread or fscanf, I haven't touched c in a while. Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
while (fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != NULL && str1[0] != '\n')
```

If `fgets()` reads a newline it stores it in the string, and returns `NULL` if it encounters a `EOF`. 
This way you get the input and test if `fgets()` encounters `EOF` first, then you test the first character in the string (`str1[0]`) to see if it is a newline.
Remember `fgets()` returns a `char *` so you can use pointer notation `*str1` or array notation `str1[0]` to test the first character of the string.

Answer (score -2):

`// Rajat Sewal`
`#include <stdio.h>`
`#include <stdlib.h>`
`#include <string.h>`
   `typedef struct island {`
   `char *name;`
   `char *opens;`
    `char *closes;`
    `struct island *next;`
   `} island;`

`int main()`
`{`
   `printf("This is an example of linked lists using a file to read the data needed!\n");`
    `printf("to create the structs dynamically!\n\n\n");`
    `// First we need a function called island that creates the new island struct`
    `/********************************************/`
    `island* create(char *name)`
    `{`
       `island *i = malloc(sizeof(island));`
       `// set the fields on the new struct`
       `i->name = strdup(name); // strdup duplicates the string so a NEW copy is used`
       `i->opens = "09:00";`
       `i->closes = "17:00";`
       `i->next = NULL;`
       `return i;`
   `}`
   `/********************************************/`
   `void display(island *start)`
   `{`
       `island *i = start;`
       `for (;i !=NULL; i = i->next) {`
`printf("Name: %s \n  Open: %s-%s\n\n\n", i->name, i->opens,`i->closes);
    `}`
}
/********************************************/`

```
`island *start = NULL;`
`island *i = NULL;`
`island *next = NULL;`
`int j;`
`char name[80];`
`printf("Enter ^Z to finish [in windows]\n");`
`printf("Enter the names of the island you want to create:");`
`for(; (fgets(name, 80, stdin)!= NULL); i = next) {`
    `printf("Enter the next name of the island you want to create:");`
    `next = create(name);`
   ` if (start == NULL)`
       ` start = next;`
   ` if (i != NULL)`
        `i->next = next;`
`}`
`display(start);`
`return 0;`
```

`}`

Comment: Please format your code properly, as well as give an explanation on why this is a solution.